# How to send an html string from a python http web server?

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I found a python http web server from http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

```
import sys
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass  = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol     = "HTTP/1.0"

if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    port = 8000
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)

HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print "Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
httpd.serve_forever()
```

If the directory has a file named index.html, that file will be served as the initial file. If there is no index.html, then the files in the directory will be listed.

How do I modify the script so that I send a custom html to the browser?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to this? Apache and Nginx exist for a reason.  SimpleHTTPServer is a complete toy implementation, it ins't suitable for anything, really.

Comment: @TylerEaves I want to execute a command as root on the server and display its results to the browser.

Comment: Head for a minimal framework like Flask.

Comment: No need for a server, just dump the html to a file in /tmp and exec a browser

Answer (score 5):

As the name and documentation imply, `SimpleHTTPServer` is dead-simple, and intended to be used as sample code for building your own servers on top of the frameworks in the standard library.

So, if you want to do anything with it, you probably want to copy and modify [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py), or just use it as inspiration.

And if you want to do anything *serious*, you probably want to use a framework made for writing real HTTP servers like [`tornado`](http://tornadoweb.org) or [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com), or just use a stock HTTP server and delegate the dynamic pages to Python via, say, [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

But if you really want to do this, you can. There's nothing stopping you from subclassing `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and overriding its methods. For example:

```
class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def send_head(self):
        if self.translate_path(self.path).endswith('/foo'):
            body = gaping_security_hole(self.path)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
            self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(body)))
            self.end_headers()
            return StringIO(body)
        else:
            return super(MyHandler, self).send_head()
```

Obviously you can check whatever you want there instead of `endswith('/foo')`. For example, as you can see from [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py#l68), the default implementation checks `os.path.isdir`, and if it's true checks whether it `endswith('/')`, and whether the directory has anything named `index.html` or `index.htm`, before deciding what to do.

Comment: I can't get this to init `Handler = MyHandler()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Just use it like this `HandlerClass = MyHandler` and then `httpd = ServerClass (server_address, HandlerClass)` `httpd.serve_forever()`